# clang++: VS Code Debugger Setup does not show variables

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

Problem: Debugging doesn't show variables in VS Code IDE. LLDB may not connect properly.

My c++ project is compiled and run with Makefile. I link the Makefile to tasks.json and launch.json to implement debugging on the IDE. So far, I haven't been able to successfully link the debugger. When adding "miDebuggerPath," the code succeeds in building the executable, but does not run.

I am guessing that the LLDB couldn't connect. I check the LLDB path, and it is indeed correct. What might be the problem here?

In the tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "cd Directory",
            "command": "cd",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C++: Build",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "build"
            ],
            "dependsOn":["cd Directory"]
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C++: Build & Run",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "run"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "cd Directory"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

In the launch.json, if I add "miDebuggerPath" it somehow stalls the debugging run.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            //"miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/lldb", 
            //uncommenting the "miDebuggerPath" statement stalls the program
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for lldb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }],
            "preLaunchTask": "C++: Build"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Makefile has two main functions:

'make build': build executable but not run

'make run': build and run executable

```
PROJECT_TITLE:= main
CC := /usr/bin/clang++
EXTENSION := .cpp

#directory for src, bin, obj
SRC_DIR := src
BIN_DIR := bin
OBJ_DIR := obj

#flags (ldflags: lib directory ldlibs: direct lib file (.dylib/.so/.a))
CPPFLAGS := -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -Iinclude -ILibrary/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -ILibrary/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/llvm-gcc/4.2.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include -MMD -MP
CFLAGS := -Wno-deprecated-declarations
LDFLAGS := -Llib/GLFW -L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib
LDLIBS := -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit

#list source files
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*$(EXTENSION))

#list object files (.o)
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%$(EXTENSION)=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

#building executable path
EXE := $(BIN_DIR)/$(PROJECT_TITLE)

#starting run
all: $(EXE)

run: $(EXE)
    ${EXE}

build: $(OBJ) | $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o

#if obj is updated, run linker
$(EXE): $(OBJ) | $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

#if program is updated, update object
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%$(EXTENSION) |$(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#create dir
$(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(TEMP_DIR): 
    mkdir -p $@
```

When debugging (without "miDebuggerPath"), this occurs:
[image]

Comment: At no point do you add debugging flags, at least `-g`, and preferably a `-O0` as well.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks for your input! I will try adding these flags and see whether it helps.

Comment: Adding `-g` and `-O0` doesn't seem to improve the situation. I tried it during the compilation and the linking phase.

Comment: It's not they "improve the situation". `-g` is a required flag if you want to debug your code.

Comment: @sweenish I agree. Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I just mean that there should be something else that could be problematic. I tested lldb directly on terminal after debug build, and it works fine. One problem during the terminal test is that breakpoint doesn't map onto the cpp file, and I need `target.source-map` to direct the debugger to the source code. Not sure if this is the problem for VS Code.

Comment: I haven't found the bug yet, but I have found a workaround solution using the CodeLLDB extension in the VS Marketplace instead. This works fine for me.